# How to stop refresh Google maps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, subgurim-maps

```
aspx :code:    
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <div id="map">
        <cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" />
        </div>            
    C# cod:    
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     GMap1.resetMarkers(); 
     Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng gLatLng = new  Subgurim.Controles.GLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][0]), Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][1]));
     GMap1.setCenter(gLatLng, 16, Subgurim.Controles.GMapType.GTypes.Normal);
     Subgurim.Controles.GMarker oMarker = new Subgurim.Controles.GMarker(gLatLng);
     GMap1.addGMarker(oMarker);
  }
```

for every 40 sec GMap getting refreshing here. i want without GMap refresh i set new lat and lang on GMap. how can i set this new points or markers on Gmap

Comment: What does your code look like? It seems to me that you should reposition your marker instead of using the refresh function you are using now.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect your computer from the internet

Sorry mate, had to do it :D:D:D

Answer (score 0):

```
// Enable the visual refresh
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```